# app crashes on fast uisearchbar text entry

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, arrays, uisearchbar

My app shows the following error when type into a `UISearchBar` quickly

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 206 beyond bounds [0 .. 13]
```

when typing slowly, search works just fine

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        sortedCustomerID= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        sortedDefaultsShipingID=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        isFiltered = true;
        if (text !=nil)
        {
            NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName contains[cd] %@ ",text];
            [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        }
        else
        {
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"All"];
            [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        }
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
        {
            // Handle error
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            exit(-1);  // Fail
        }
       _fetchedObjects = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;

        for (int i =0 ; i<_fetchedObjects.count ; i ++)
        {
            [filteredTableData addObject:[[_fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"lastName"]objectAtIndex:i]];

            [sortedCustomerID addObject:[[_fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"customerID"]objectAtIndex:i]];
            [sortedDefaultsShipingID addObject:[[_fetchedObjects valueForKey:@"defaultShippingID"]objectAtIndex:i]];
          }
       }

       NSLog(@" name=%@ customerID=%@ shippingID=%@", filteredTableData,sortedCustomerID,sortedDefaultsShipingID);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Return data and update on the main thread
            // Task 3: Deliver the data to a 3rd party component (always do on the main thread).

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't have any experience of `UISearchBar`, but would the method you posted be called for *any* change of text?  if so you will be spawning threads like mad, and concurrently accessing `fetchedResultsController` etc.

Answer (score 2):

With most exceptions you get quite a bit of additional information that can help you figure out what is going wrong.

In this case, the exception description is telling you that you tried to access an `NSArray` element that does not exist. It would appear that the `NSArray` object in question is `_fetchedObjects`. Furthermore, based on the name, it would seem that it is an ivar.

So consider what is happening here. Character is entered in search bar. Async operation gets launched and data is retrieved, stored in `_fetchedObjects` and then accessed. However, what happens when several of these operations get created very quickly and *each* of them try to access the same `_fetchedObjects`?

I would consider storing the search results in a local variable and then assigning it to an ivar/property at the end of the async op if you really need to store it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your for loop to

```
for (int i =0 ; i<_fetchedObjects.count ; i ++)
{
        [filteredTableData addObject:[[_fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"lastName"]];
        [sortedCustomerID addObject:[[_fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"customerID"]];
        [sortedDefaultsShipingID addObject:[[_fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"defaultShippingID"]];
 }
```